# How can we protect our MVC2 code?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-2, deployment, web-deployment-project

In a normal ASP.NET Website there is a [Web Deployment Project](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/28/vs-2008-web-deployment-project-support-released.aspx) that we can use to pre-compile our entire website and then we can safely upload this project to our production server in order to protect our code.

> **What can we do** for ASP.NET MVC 2?

---

Link to it as is available today (RTM version)

> [Visual Studio® 2010 Web Deployment Projects - RTW](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=89f2c4f5-5d3a-49b6-bcad-f776c6edfa63)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you install the latest security patches for your operating system and hire a good network administrator. No kidding. No matter what you do if a hacker gains control over the server he will get the code under one form or another even if it is precompiled. This being said it is a good idea to precompile the application and deploy only the assemblies instead of the source code. You could also consider [obfuscating](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&q=.net+obfuscators&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m2&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=6e8733203d1b4e27) it also but this is something usually done for client applications which you deploy to your users computers and less frequently done in server side applications because you control the server.

Comment: I know that, but my question was "How do I do that", as there is no Web Deployment project in VS2010. The Project Installer is still in beta for VS2010 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=711a2eef-b107-4784-9063-c978edc498cd&displaylang=en

Comment: Yes it is in beta. This is no problem. Download it and install it. It works very well. I am using it since VS2010 has been released. It is a very good package.

Comment: @balexandre, the link you provided notes that it has been released and has a link to the RTW version.

Comment: @adrift ehehe, dumb me :) got it (now you know that I'm on the 95% of users that only read the 1st paragraph) ;) ... you're in the 5% that read all :D